# Functional Component React - Update 1 state cause entire page to re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Thank you all in advance for your help.
I am not sure why when i updated the `percentageDone` state in my `loadDataFunction()` will update the `RenderData1Component` where it shouldn't. Shouldn't it update only when data1 changed?

I have a piece of code like this.

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(null);
  const [percentageDone, setPercentageDone] = useState(0);


  LoadDataFunction(){
    // calling multiple apis (let say 10) in a promise and call setPercentageDone() whenever 1 of the Apis is done.
  }
  useEffect( () => {
     LoadDataFunction()
  },[])
  useEffect( () => {
     if (condition are met) {
       LoadDataFunction() // Reload Data All over again for latest data
     }
  }, [condition])

  return (
    loading ? percentageDone
            : <RenderData1Component data={data1}>
  )
```

I want to update `<RenderData1Component data={data1}>` only when i updated `data1` state not percentageDone. but whenever i am updating setPercentageDone() it also trigger a re-render for `<RenderData1Component data={data1}>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but this may help you.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data1, setData1] = useState(null);
const [percentageDone, setPercentageDone] = useState(0);

const loadDataFunction = async () => {
  // Perform API calls and update percentageDone
};

useEffect(() => {
  loadDataFunction().then(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (condition) {
    setLoading(true);
    loadDataFunction().then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
}, [condition]);

return (
  loading ? (
    <div>{percentageDone}% Loading...</div>
  ) : (
    <RenderData1Component data={data1} />
  )
);
```

It may be possible that you're giving multiple conditions, which may be causing problems. Check it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What you posted is what i end up doing, but the problem come from the component itself XD . I posted answer in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the help.

I found the problem. The problem came from the `<RenderData1Component/>` itself. The theme code get's run every time when the state updated and it updated the css class for that CustomSwitch element which causes the re-render.

My solution is to move the custom switch outside of this component and make it an external component.

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
const CustomSwitch = styled(Switch)(({ theme }) => ({.........}) //Cause of re-render
```